# How to get the userid from the session_key in django_session table?

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-decorators

I have a UserInfo table as

```
 class UserInfo(models.Model):
  group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
  email = models.EmailField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True,
    validators=[validators.validate_email])
  passwd = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
  dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
  zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
  avatar = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
  status = models.BooleanField(default=True)         #Active or Inactive
  email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now I want to write a decorator to check whether the user is logged in or not before performing any action like creating an event etc..

1. One way I think is to store the session_key when the user logged and get the user id for that session and compare with the userid in the django_session table.

For this to work out I need to store user_id in the django_session table how to do that?

1. After storing it how to get the user_id from the session id that was generated?

Or it would be very helpful if you tell me any idea on how to write a decorator to check whether the user is logged in or not.

Comment: Have you checked documentation? Is there any reason that you can't use the login required decorator which is available? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator

Comment: can u please tell how that decorator works?

Comment: I think that will be used for only auth_user table.

Comment: decorators are callables returning other callables. You can find e.g. in documentation as well as explanation on http://passingcuriosity.com/2009/writing-view-decorators-for-django/

Comment: I need to check whether the user is logged in or not without using the decorator u have mentioned.

Comment: In your view function you can check request.user.is_authenticated()